# in Laravel Model Factories when I do a make() and set a timestamp field, the function is trying to hit the database

Tags: php, laravel

This is hitting the database

```
    $organization = factory(ilos\Models\Organization::class)->make([
        "created_at" => Carbon::now()->subWeek(3),
        "is_paid" => true,
        "paid_until" => Carbon::now()->addWeek(1),
    ]);
```

This is not

```
    $organization = factory(ilos\Models\Organization::class)->make([
        "is_paid" => true,
        "paid_until" => Carbon::now()->addWeek(1),
    ]);
```

Isn't make supposed to never hit the database?
how can I achieve the expected outcome? 
I need to set the created_at to check if the organization is still in trial (this is for a unit test) and I don't want to touch the database.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is it trying to do with the database Daniel? Also do you have anything special in the Model on that column?

Comment: it just queries, this is a unit test so I have it set up a wrong password when I run the unit tests. Whenever the test try to hit a database I get an error. For some reason the function make() when I add any timestamp field is doing a query to the database. I want to prevent this behaviur (I'm mocking the function so isn't supposed to hit it. If you want to see my full code I can show you.

Comment: I'm wondering if its trying to get information about the timestamp format from the database or something like that. Might be worth asking on the slack channel https://larachat.slack.com/ perhaps someone has encountered it before.